# Hardware Multiplication ALU

Tags: assembly, mips, multiplication, alu

I have multiplicand 5 , multiplier 7
which they are binary representation :

> 5 = 0101 , 7 = 0111 (4-bit)

**Register A** to save the data to be multiplied(Multiplicand).

**Register B** to save the multiplier data (Multiplier).

**Register P** to save multiplication results.

Here is what I've tried
[image]

Here is my reference on a journal:

[image]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?  the binary result should be **00100011** (decimal : 35)

Comment: Owh, sorry, my bad, i saw someone also post in same topic and posted image tho ... thank you ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During addition, you failed to propagate the carry to left and have erroneously labelled it "carry out".  It should be added to bit to left, this will also generate a carry so repeat the process.